# sorting numbers stored in text field in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

i have a mySQL database with a text field in which is stored a number.
i need to produce a recordset sorted in descending numerical order.
this works fine until we get to numbers greater than 10 ie

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
10
1
```

is there a simple way of sorting this 'correctly' ?
(yes, i know i should have numbers in a numerical field, but i'm working with what i have :))

i'm using the results on an asp/vbscript/jquery page so maybe even a client-side solution is viable...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY ABS(text_column) DESC
```

Or, if you also have to deal with negative values:

```
ORDER BY CAST(text_column AS SIGNED) DESC
```

Comment: perfect solution.. thank you... didn't think it'd be that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to type cast it to `INTEGER` using  `CAST` function in MySQL:

```
ORDER BY CAST(text_column AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Comment: You are right. It works. It doesn't if you leave the `unsigned`.

Comment: ya INTEGER keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
... ORDER BY text_column * 1
```